# Adding 3 costs together to form a total using python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I'm taking a bunch of inputs with as if it were a receipt for mini vacation and trying to add all three categories up to make a total. I keep getting the cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects problem that I can't seem to get around no matter what I do.

```
def main():
    airfareCost = int(input ("Airfare Cost"))
    hotelCost = int(input ("Hotel Cost"))
    mealsCost = int(input ("Meals Cost"))
    Total = (int(airfareCost + hotelCost + mealsCost))
    print "Mini-vacation time!"
    print "Below lists the expenses for your trip to the Florida Keys."
    print " "
    print "  Item                Cost"
    print "  Airfare:            "+"$"+int(airfareCost)
    print "  Hotel:              "+"$"+hotelCost
    print "  Meals:              "+"$"+mealsCost
    print "  ---------------------------"
    print "  Total:              "+"$"+Total
    print "  Have a fantastic trip!"

main()
```

Comment: You need to do `"$"+str(mealsCost)`. <-- note the `str` which type-casts the value to string

Comment: Okay, thank you, this seems to have fixed this concatenation problem but now when people input the three values the total just displays three of the numbers combined without actually adding them up ;/

Comment: that's because I guess you are using `str` at the time of input (and probably removed int)? You need to keep int as in your current code, and use str at the place where you are concatenating with the string. It should work fine

Comment: You need to carefully consider when you want an `int` vs a `str`, you need both here.

Comment: Ah, this works as well! I guess I wasn't supposed to change the int from the 3 inputs I'd had, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main():
    airfareCost = int(input ("Airfare Cost"))
    hotelCost = int(input ("Hotel Cost"))
    mealsCost = int(input ("Meals Cost"))
    Total = int(airfareCost + hotelCost + mealsCost)
    print "Mini-vacation time!"
    print "Below lists the expenses for your trip to the Florida Keys.\n"
    print "  Item                Cost"
    print "  Airfare:            ${}".format(airfareCost)
    print "  Hotel:              ${}".format(hotelCost)
    print "  Meals:              ${}".format(mealsCost)
    print "  ---------------------------"
    print "  Total:              ${}".format(Total)
    print "  Have a fantastic trip!"
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to have worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: please upvote/accept any answer which have helped you.

Comment: I'll be sure to accept it, makes me wait a bit though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly cast the integer values to strings.

```
'somestring' + str(someinteger)
```